# How to compile a PGF/TikZ plot several times using the standalone package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, external-files, standalone, tikz-external

In my main document `mwe.tex` is a PGF/TikZ plot integrated using the package `standalone`.
This plot contains several frames so that several axis with different axis scalings/ axis sections  are displayed.
The plot has to be compiled minimum twice, to get the full legend properly.

Is it possible to define the number of external compilations to the standalone command, for instance as a parameter of the standalone command or as part of the build/latex options?

```
% !TEX root = ./mwe.tex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8

% --- Pgfplot ---

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{./tikzPlotStandalone.tex}

\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{color4}{rgb}{0.5, 0.0, 0.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
 compat=newest,
 width=14.5cm,
 height=5.5cm,
 scale only axis,
 grid,
 xmin=-5.5,
 xmax=5.5,
 tick align=outside,
}

% Frame 1
\begin{axis}[
 xlabel={ $ x $ },
 xtick pos=bottom,
 ymin=-10.0,
 ymax=10.0,
 y axis line style={color1},
 ytick style={color1},
 yticklabel style={color1},
 axis y line*=left,
 ylabel={ $f_{1}(x)$ },
 ylabel style=color1,
 ]
 \addplot[
  color=color1,
  mark size=2.0pt,
  mark=square*,
  mark options={solid},
 ]{ -2 * x - 2 };
 \label{tikzPlot1}
\end{axis}

% Frame 2
\begin{axis}[
 color=color2,
 scale only axis,
 hide x axis,
 ymin=-10.0,
 ymax=30.0,
 axis y line*=left,
 ylabel={ $f_{2}(x)$ },
 every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=-2.0cm},
 every tick/.style={xshift=-2.0cm},
 every y tick label/.append style={xshift=-2.0cm},
 ]
 \addplot[
  color=color2,
  mark size=2.0pt,
  mark=*,
  mark options={solid,fill=color2},
 ]{ -3 * x + 9 };
 \label{tikzPlot2}
\end{axis}

% Frame 3
\begin{axis}[
 color=color3,
 scale only axis,
 hide x axis,
 ymin=-5.0,
 ymax=15.0,
 ytick style={color3},
 axis y line*=right,
 ylabel={ $f_{3}(x)$ },
 ylabel style=color3,
 ]
 \addplot[
  color=color3,
  mark size=2.0pt,
  mark=triangle*,
  mark options={solid,fill=color3}
 ]{ 2 * x - 3 };
 \label{tikzPlot3}
\end{axis}

% Frame 4
\begin{axis}[
 scale only axis,
 hide x axis,
 ymin=-10.0,
 ymax=10.0,
 axis y line*=right,
 tick align=outside,
 every outer y axis line/.style={
  color4, xshift=2.0cm,
 },
 every tick/.style={
  color4, xshift=2.0cm,
 },
 every y tick label/.append style={
  color4, xshift=2.0cm,
 },
 ylabel={ $f_{4}(x)$ },
 ylabel style={color4},
 legend pos=north east,
 ]
 
 \addlegendimage{refstyle={tikzPlot2}} \addlegendentry{ \color{color2} $f_{2}(x)$ }
 \addlegendimage{refstyle={tikzPlot1}} \addlegendentry{ \color{color1} $f_{1}(x)$ }
 \addlegendimage{refstyle={tikzPlot3}} \addlegendentry{ \color{color3} $f_{3}(x)$ }

 \addplot[
  color=color4,
  mark size=2.0pt,
  mark=diamond*,
  mark options={solid,fill=color4}
 ]{ 2 * x + 0 };
 \addlegendentry{ \color{color4}  $f_{4}(x)$ }
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\end{filecontents}

% --- Main document ---

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\includestandalone[
 width=1.0\textwidth,
 mode=buildmissing,
 build={latexoptions={-interaction=batchmode -shell-escape -halt-on-error -output-directory "./"}},
]{./tikzPlotStandalone}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not compile the pfgplot separately and include the pdf.. Far too complicated and will get much worse with large documents. Work on the plot, compile and check the result, and the main document will update.

Comment: @algae not to answer for the OP, but for instance I switch between beamer and article and with the includegraphics inclusion I lose the font consistency with my text.

Comment: @algae Thank you for the advice. I handle a large document (>350 pages) with a large amount of figures (>150 illustrations). So far I am coping well with the package and in my opinion the basic idea of the package is quite good. However, I am not so familiar with the usage of the package and did not find any information regarding my problem in the user manual nor the WWW. Maybe there is no simple solution. In this case, it can help others who also encounter this situation or as a discussion point for a feature request.

Comment: @TomTom I mentioned this because in my experience, when following your approach I had the same problem as with your question plus more. The fact is that the only difference is in using `\includestandalone` vs. `\includefigure`. Your document is also quite large, so you should probably have a makefile that checks for changes made to your figures and recompile's if necessary. Also you don't seem to be using `externalise` which could speed up compilation time.

Comment: @algae Basically Latex and TikZ are nice solutions by its own.
But first steps are hard due to the large TikZ/pgfplot manual and the inheritance of parameter settings from a Latex class down to a TikZ plot.
Especially, when you have to use a given Latex/TikZ class. I therefore conclude, there should be a way for strict separation between Latex and TikZ.
The approach of the package `standalone` is well suited for this.
I opened a feature request in the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/50/support-for-compiling-pgf-tikz-several), hoping it is considered.

Comment: I agree. And the natural way to separate the two is to have tikz/pgf in separate standalone files which generate their own pdfs (with single shot compilation, that solves your first problem) and simply include them in your main document. Anyway this is beyond me, I can't think of any workflow optimisations to using `\includestandalone`. IMO tikz/pgf need to be redone and made into an independent 'graphics language'.